# problem with calling emacsclientw from command line

Tags: windows, emacs, command-line, org-mode

I'm calling emacsclientw on Win7 to process an Org file.  I want the Emacs buffer to be closed after processing, so that if the file is edited outside Emacs and the call is resent to emacsclientw it will process the changed file.  I would like for the buffer to be killed at the end of the emacsclient --eval.  If I can't get that then it would be okay to just get rid of the 'File has changed, reload (yes or no)' prompt that I get when redoing command line call after editing the file outside emacs.

Here's the command line call, which works fine except that the buffer remains open in the Emacs frame on screen even after the kill-buffer function (although it says 'pushed to the kill ring').  I know kill-buffer is not supposed to do what I want on an emacs client; I've also tried server-edit and server-kill-buffer with no better result.:

```
c:/users/herbert/emacsclientw -n --eval ^"(let ((org-export-
babel-evaluate nil)) (progn (find-file \^"c:/users/herbert/desktop/org_files
/gtdsample.org\^") (org-export-as-html-and-open nil) (kill-buffer) ))^"
```

Is there some way to get the buffer in Emacs to close?  Or, is there some way to just stop it from bringing up prompt if I try to redo the same command after editing the gtdsample.org file outside of Emacs?

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought, you might try (server-edit) or (server-switch-buffer) instead of (kill-buffer).

Comment: Thanks.  As I said I did also try (server-edit) and (server-kill-buffer), but not (server-switch-buffer).  However, answered turned out not to be related to client/server issue at all, was that code above was leaving me in different buffer than one I wanted killed.  So modified it to ensure correct buffer and it worked.  Thanks again for the input.